# Address sanitization error.heap buffer overflow

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
 vector<vector<int>> answer ;

    int s=intervals.size();
    int i=0;
    int k=0;

    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        if(intervals[k][k+1]>intervals[k+1][k])
        {
            answer.push_back( {intervals[k][k],intervals[k+1][k+1]} );

        }
       
    }
  }
```

no matter whats the size of the vector merge i am always getting this error I don't understand whats the problem

Comment: Try using `intervals.at(A).at(B)` instead of `intervals[A][B]` to check if there are any out-of-range access.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.  We need to see how you create and populate the vector.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/ i am solving this code in leet code and this is the exact same code I have written on my IDE

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` - That helps _a lot_!

Comment: @AnshikaSharma: There's no code visible at that link, and anyway, your code should be in the question here, not behind a link.  A [mcve] means a complete program (headers, main function, everything), together with input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You forgot `return answer;`, so your code has undefined behaviour. A decent compiler will warn about this.